# Валидация форм JS

Tags: javascript, form

При валидации формы, когда заполнены все поля, проверяемые в selInputs() выскакивает alert дважды. Посдкажите в чем проблема?

```js
var newsForm = $('#add_news_form'),
  themesForm = $('#add_theme_form');

function selInputs(arg) {
  var title = arg.children('.add_mat_title').find('.text'),
    shortDesc = arg.children('.add_mat_short').find('.text'),
    text = arg.children('.add_mat_text').find('.text'),
    source = arg.children('.add_mat_source').find('.text'),
    tags = arg.children('.add_mat_tags').find('.text'),
    inputs = [];

  inputs.push(title, shortDesc, text, source, tags);

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].val() == null || inputs[i].val() == '') {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

function formValidation(form) {
  $(this).submit(function() {
    if (selInputs($(this)) === false) {
      alert('Заполните все поля!')
      return false;
    }
  });
}

formValidation(newsForm);
formValidation(themesForm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так у Вас функция вызывается дважды. И получается так, что если в обеих формах `selInputs($(this))` == false, alert тоже выскакивает дважды. Попробуйте добавть в аргументы каждой формы вот это: `onsubmit="formValidation(this)"` и убрать все вызовы formValidation внизу скрипта.